# How to enable UTF-8 to Unicode translation?

Tags: mysql, delphi, character-encoding, delphi-xe3, unidac

```
Database: utf8 
Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

I have the following problem:

When I execute my query everything is written correctly to the table except the `Chinese` characters and `Cyrillic` characters shows me only in the table field "???????".

[image]

Is there an option to change the charset in the unidac componenet or at the mysql server?

Comment: Have you tried `Connection.SpecificOptions.Values['MySQL.UseUnicode'] := 'True';`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Post it as answer i will accept it.

Comment: @The downvoter: Please write down as comment why you voted down ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set a driver specific option to enable Unicode translation:

```
Connection.SpecificOptions.Values['MySQL.UseUnicode'] := 'True';
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the [set names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) SQL command after you establish the connection like `SET NAMES utf8`, but you would be responsible for using the proper field types.